# How to avoid every thing show in list?

Tags: flutter

I am getting the response from API and integrate it into my widget. I have two API. From `sendPagesDataRequest()` is my first API function. Then the second response is from `getDetails()`. My first **API** have **'Id'**, 'avatar', 'username'. Then my second **API** have 'reply' and **'Id'**. My first API will show every thing but my second API some ID have reply some id did not have. The Id is same in both API. So the result should like if that Id have 'reply' haveDetails is true then will show the details. Now the problem is when I press the button to call the getDetails function, every card come out the details.

```
 class _State extends State<MyProject> {
  GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      body: return Paginator.listView(
        key: paginatorGlobalKey,
        pageLoadFuture: sendPagesDataRequest,
        pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetterPages,
        listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
        loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
        errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
        emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
        totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
        pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
        scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    );
  }

  Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(response.body);
      return pagesData;
    } catch (e){

    }
  }

  List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
    List<Project> list = [];
    pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
      list.add(value);
    });
    return list;
  }

Widget listItemBuilder(dynamic item, int index) {
    return  Card:
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
            child: 
            Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.avatar.toString()),
                  radius: 20.0,
                  ),          
                  title: Text(item.userName.toString()),
                 )
                ),

              ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: comment.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return    
            ),
            FlatButton(onPressed: () => getDetails(item, context)),
             haveDetails ? Text(details[index].reply.toString()) : Container(),
            ]
            )
            ),
          ],
        )
  )
}

Future getDetails(dynamic item, BuildContext context) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    final decodedData = pagesDataFromJson1(response.body);
    var reply = decodedData.data.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < decodedData.data.length; i++) {
      details.add(decodedData.data[i]);
    }
    setState(() {
      haveDetails = true;
    });
  }

  Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 160.0,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget errorWidgetMaker(PagesData pagesData, retryListener) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text("error"),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: retryListener,
          child: Text('Retry'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget emptyListWidgetMaker(PagesData pagesData) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('No data in the list'),
    );
  }

  int totalPagesGetter(PagesData pagesData) {
    return pagesData.lastPage;
  }

  bool pageErrorChecker(PagesData pagesData) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either it is too simple or I didn't understand your question. Either way, let me try.

You'll have to update listItemsGetterPages() as below :

```
List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
    List<Project> list = [];
    pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
      if (value.haveDetails) {
           list.add(value);
      }
    });
    return list;
  }
```

This is nearest to your code. There are better ways to deal with List. For example, you could write :

```
list = pagesData.where((item) => item.haveDetails).toList();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I try already still cannot. I have upload the image at above. You can see first card and second card have ID=1 's response. Actually I want to show if my second API have same ID response then will show the text if not then will don't show the text. Now both card show ID=1 's text